# How to import TypeScript file with a .js extension using Vue CLI?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2

I want to do this:

```
import { pushState } from 'vue-router/src/util/push-state.js'
```

However, for some reason, the developers of vue-router wrote the `push-state.js` in TypeScript but left it with a `.js` extension. So when I first tried to import it, it gave me the following error when I ran `vue-cli-service serve`:

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (25:30)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> export function pushState (url?: string, replace?: boolean) {
```

I thus modified my `vue.config.js` like this:

```
module.exports = {
    ...
    chainWebpack: config => {
        ...
        config.module
            .rule('ts')
            .test(/push-state/)
            .use('ts-loader')
                .loader('ts-loader')
                .end();
        return config
    }
}
```

and my `tsconfig.json` is as follows:

```
{
    "include": [
        "node_modules/vue-router/src/util/push-state.js",
        "./node_modules/vue-router/src/util/push-state.js",
        "./buffer.ts",
    ],
    "exclude":[],
}
```

Now it does not throw any error, but `pushState` is simply `undefined`. I tried with `require('vue-router/src/util/push-state.js')` but it simply returns an empty object. I have `ts-loader` and `typescript` in my `devDependencies`.

Comment: It may have been written in TypeScript, but I would hope that the 'compiled' script file is JavaScript. Are you sure the file contains TypeScript, because that would be weird IMO.

Comment: The minified version in `/dist/` does not export the function I want, so I'm getting it through `/src/`. I suppose it's TypeScript because it declares a function like this:
`function pushState (url?: string, replace?: boolean)`. That's not JavaScript. Do you think it's something else?